# How can i get the best performance when dealing with large database?

Tags: php, mysql, session, scalability

I'm programming a browser game in which there are spells table, items table.. ect. Each table has thousands of rows. What i do to handle this is the following.

Upon login, i store the entire database in the user's session. That includes only the tables that are not going to be changed by the user's input. For example, the spells table contains only information about the spells. How much damage they deal, what level is required for the player to have that spell, ect. The user only reads that data, never writes to it.

Let's say that the user wants to buy a specific spell. I can't aford the PHP code to go and check each array in the session variable for the spell id. Instead ->

```html
    <?php
  // Load all database spells
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM spells");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION["spells_db"] = $result;
  ?>
```

So, what happens is -> i store all database spells into this session variable. Using \PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC i change the spell array key to the spell ID. This way i already know the spell key.

If i ever need to search for a spell information by id, the id of the spell is also the key of the array row of that spell. So instead using in_array() to make the PHP search every single row of the array, to find which inner array contains the relevant spell ID, i can just tell it which row it is. This way i saved a lot of performance.

But on the other side, each individual user stores the entire database on his session. In time this will cause my website to have scalability issues. I know that it is better to store data in the session, instead making query every time to ask the database if something is changed. In my case, when something gets changed, first i change it in the session, then i change it in the database. And every time an user refreshes the page, session data is displayed. But talking about large data storage like storing the entire database, makes my head blow up. So, any advice on how to deal with this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Horrible, to store the entire db in a session. That creates a lot of useless I/O. Just use db indexes wisely, and prepare statements for re-use. That should be a lot faster than what you're doing now.

Comment: Well...  the player inventory page contains 15 slots. If they are full, then 15 queries will get triggered in order to get the relevant information for those items(Item name..ect). Since the session variable contains data that is never going to be changed, then can i store that data in a text document or something. Simply storing the database tables that are not going to be changed in a text document for more performance? Does that sound like a solution? Or maybe that will cause performance solutions as well? Searching every text row for the spell ID ect... sounds horrible also.

Comment: It depends on how you run php, if session info is reloaded on each HTTP-request with php-fpm, the overhead doesn't make it worthwile. When you run php as a statefull application, caching will help. Alternatively you could even cache the spells accross sessions using [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Comment: Look at using [memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) to store commonly used data. That will unload your sessions and reduce your database IO

Comment: `If they are full, then 15 queries will get triggered in order to get the relevant information for those items(Item name..ect).`...why not just one query to get all inventory items associated with the player? Seems like maybe there's a bit of general inefficiency in the way the application is implemented, perhaps.

Comment: `Since the session variable contains data that is never going to be changed, then can i store that data in a text document or something. Simply storing the database tables that are not going to be changed in a text document for more performance`...depends how you're going to need to query the data. You seem to be assuming that database access is inefficient. It's not. Databases are **extremely** efficient at scanning and fetching large sets of data and searching/filtering and sorting it on demand, especially if you set the right indexes on the tables and have a sensible schema design.

Comment: `I know that it is better to store data in the session, instead making query every time to ask the database if something is changed` ... generally only for small things which you access in every single request, like the current user's name and ID, for example. If you genuinely have an issue with database I/O (which you've presented no actual evidence of) then potentially a caching solution as Tangentially mentioned might be appropriate, but again depends if you then need to search/filter/sort that data each time you access it.

Comment: ADyson thank you so much for those answers man. Yes i was assiming that the database access is inefficient. I use 15 queries for the following reason. There is a table called playerinventory, every column of it is like "slot1","slot2".. ect. Those columns contain numbers(item ids). Then in the PHP,  if the relevant slot is not 0, then the PHP accesses the other table called items, it contains thousands of rows for example. It does query for each player slot which ID is not 0.

Comment: I was thinking i could use 15 queries but at the same time put LIMIT 1 to every query, will that make difference? I saw in google that it does but not sure if it will have much of a effect if there are 100 people online at my website spaming refresh.

Comment: I stored everything in the session because my programmer friend told me to do so. He works as a programmer since 6 years, and i blindly took his advice without reading anything. Now i must rework my entire project from 0 because of this brutal mistake.

Comment: it sounds like a lot of your data is static (not ever changing) but spread across multiple tables.  you should be able to store it in memory in your service?

Comment: `There is a table called playerinventory, every column of it is like "slot1","slot2".. ect` ...this is a design flaw, the data is de-normalised. Instead you would have just three columns - player ID, item ID, slot. So if a player has 15 items they would have 15 rows in the table with their ID. That way you can easily get all their items with one query. You'll find if you correctly normalise your schema it makes writing queries a lot easier and more efficient.

Comment: `I stored everything in the session because my programmer friend told me to do so`...are you sure that's what he really meant? Like I said, for very small pieces of data that's useful, but it's not a general solution, as I think you have now realised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you test it first using the database. I suppose its MySQL. It can handle gigabytes of data and millions of rows in a table, fast. The important is indexing. Thousands of rows is not too much for MySQL (assuming you don't have huge rows with several varchar(5000) and such).

(Those keys you were saying should probably by the indexes in your database table, and I have a gut feeling those are your autoincrement primary keys, so they will be selected fast.)

**PHP Session data must be stored somewhere too**

- If you left session storage to default, than the data is stored in a file on disk. That means disk write and those are slower then any modern database (even on SSD) because the databases would cache (into RAM) and optimize.
- If you store sessions in RAM and you do have a lot of data, you will definitely run out of RAM.
- If you store your session in the database... you know

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I readed everything i need to know. I guess i have to rework everything from 0 again. So much time wasted. I got a programmer friend who does programming as his primary job for 6 years, he told me to do that. In my head i already imagined how i can fix everything i build it the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

KISS.

If you are updating both `$_SESSION` and the database table, that adds complexity, sluggishness, etc.  And potential errors.  And potential consistency issues.

Assuming that you are fetching *one* spell from the spells table, that will take about 1ms.  And you can have multiple queries running simultaneously.

I suggest you use the database heavily without $_SESSION, time actions, then decide which need speeding up.  *Then* adding indexes, etc might help.  Or switching to $_SESSION *might* be warranted.

Don't get sucked into "premature optimization".

A bigger problem will occur if your game gets popular -- a single server will not suffice.  But once you spread the game across multiple servers, $_SESSION becomes unusable -- it is limited to one server.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thank you for the time you took to respond.

Comment: @Diablo13 - You are welcome.  And Welcome to stackoverflow.